# Is it possible in airflow to run a single task on multiple worker nodes i.e running a task in distributed way

Tags: kubernetes, celery, airflow

I am using spring batch to create a workflow of batch job. The single batch job takes 2 hrs to complete(data to be processed ~ 1 million) so decided to run in distributed way where one task will be distributed across multiple worker nodes, that way it can execute in short time. The other jobs (all are working in distributed manner) in workflow need to run in sequential manner one after other. The jobs are multi node distributed jobs(master/slave architecture) that need to run one after another.

Now, I was considering to deploy the workflow on airflow. So, while exploring that I could not find any way to run a single task that distributes across multiple machine. Is it possible in airflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a task using `Spark` framework. Spark allows you to process the data on multiple nodes in a distributed fashion.

You can then use [`SparkSubmitOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark/stable/operators.html) to align the task in your DAG.

Comment: Actually, we are using spring batch to process the 1 million dataset. I think Spark can handle as it is Spark functionality to distribute the task on multiple node and then process. But, in spring batch its not intrinsic property of the framework. Does Airflow , provide any such functionality where a single task can be distributed across multiple nodes. Regarding intercommunication between nodes and distributed processing, that will be handled by spring batch with the help of JMS queue